# How to create a custom popup menu for filter in toolbar?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, popup

I want to create a menu with multiple checkbox like in the video. I searched a lot and tried a number of ways: created Dialog but could not locate it under button, created popup menu but was impossible to customize it. Maybe I am in wrong way, maybe there is a better option to achieve it.
Any kind of tip can be useful for me

What I want:
[image: What I want to achieve]

What I have:[image]

My actionBar xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white"
    android:outlineProvider="none"
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/white"
    android:divider="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_white" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_text_background"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_filter"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:hint="Toshkent Shahar"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```